# UITableViews in different UIViewControllers share delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, share

I have seen lots of questions asking multiple table views in the SAME view controller. But my situation is the opposite:
I have several UITableViews that have the exact functionality in several different UIViewControllers. I would like to know, how can I make all these UITableViews in DIFFERENT UIViewControllers share the same delegate methods so that if i modify, say, the code in

```
-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

This change would take place for all the UITableViews, instead of me going into each single view controller and do modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this functionality. There are 2 ways I can think of on the top of my head.

1. Create a subclass of `UITableView` and create a method, lets say `customCellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you implement your shared functionality. Then in your view controllers make tableViews be subclasses of this custom `UITableView` and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` call that `customCellForRowAtIndexPath:`
2. Abstract your viewControllers. Create some sort of `BaseViewController` that will have shared functionality like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Then just subclass your viewControllers from `BaseViewController`.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Yes these solutions are also what I can think of that are elegant. Between the two I prefer subclassing UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have multiple view controller **classes** if they have the same logic. You can just have multiple **instances** of the same class. For example, you have a `SomeTableViewController` that contains your logic, and in StoryBoard, just add new view controllers that are instances of that class.

If you need the controllers to be slightly different, you can still create a generic class that contains the common elements and inherit your different controller classes from it.

Comment: Hi, only the table views in the view controllers are doing the same thing, the view controllers can have other funcionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the delegate (and if needed data store) for both tables.  Just include the delegate in both places and set it.

```
[self.myTable setDelegate:myTableDelegate];
[self.myTable setDataSource:myTableDelegate];
```

Comment: I have tried to set the delegate to a NSObject who complies to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, but looks like the delegate methods in this NSObject never get called.